# Graphql Prisma OR operator not working for two columns

Tags: apollo-server, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I tried to query track records which either title or lyric contain "cat". But only record return if both title and lyric have cat. May I know how to query by OR operator.

Query

```
query Tracks($where: TrackWhereInput) {
  tracks(where: $where) {
    id
    title
    lyric
    youtube_url
    mp3_url
  }
}
```

Variables

```
{
  "where": {
    "OR": [
      {
        "title": {
          "contains": "cat"
        },
        "lyric": {
          "contains": "cat"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass conditions to `OR` operator in different objects. You've passed an object array but both conditions are in same object. Conditions in same object use `AND` operator.

Your fixed code would be:

```
{
  "where": {
    "OR": [
      {
        "title": {
          "contains": "cat"
        },
      },
      {
        "lyric": {
          "contains": "cat"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```